# mongodb cross-collection "NOT-IN" query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

Assuming a setup like this:

**stores**

```json
    {
      name: "store1",
      category: "category1"
    },
    {
      name: "store2",
      category: "category2"
    }
```

**products**

```json
    {
      store_name: "store1",
      name: "product1"
    },
    {
      store_name: "store2",
      name: "product2"
    }
```

with hundreds of millions of records in each collection.

I need to query all **product** names for **stores** with **category** != some_parameter. The example above for category **category1** should return product2 because store2 has category2 (not category1).

I can't change the DB collections. Is it possible to use $lookup stage within an aggregation pipeline to perform "NOT IN" against another collection? something like: find all products with store not in (find all stores with category = category_param)

Comment: It might be more efficient to use aggregation to query the stores for the `!category`, and then $lookup the products in those stores.

Comment: Remember the mongodb rule of thumb **data that is accessed together should be stored together**, store store details in products document as well so don't need to lookup/join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- `$lookup` - to fetch **store** information for each **product**.
- `$set` with `$first` - Since first step will return an array that will always have one item, we will take that item.
- `$match` with `$ne` - to filter for all the documents where **category** is not equal to the requested category.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "stores",
      "localField": "store_name",
      "foreignField": "name",
      "as": "store"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "store": {
        "$first": "$store"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "store.category": {
        "$ne": "category1"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wxINpbQaKuI)